# send emails to multiple users in laravel with an $array["1@1.com","2@2.com"]

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.6, multiple-users

First of all thanks all of you for your time. I have a question, I need to send multiple emails and I have the var

```
$contact['email'] = $request->get('email');
```

which returns the emails of the db users with `$array['b@a.com','a@a.com']` How can I implement it?  (I'm on laravel 5.6 and I'm using `App\Mail\ContactEmail`)

```
public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
    $contact = [];
    $contact['email'] = $request->get('email');
    $contact['msg'] = $request->get('msg');
    $contact['name_company'] = $request->get('name_company');
    $contact['datoperfil'] = $request->get('datoperfil');
    $contact['destinatarios'] = $request->get('destinatarios');
    $contact['name'] = $request->get('name');
    $contact['cargo'] = $request->get('cargo');
    $contact['sendermail'] = $request->get('sendermail');
    $contact['fono'] = $request->get('fono');


    Mail::send(new ContactEmail($contact))
    ;


    return redirect()->route('avisos')->with('notification','Mensaje enviado!');

}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `ContactEmail` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message, use the `to` method on the `Mail` facade

```
$arr = ['b@a.com','a@a.com'];
Mail::to($arr)->send(new ContactEmail($contact));
```

[Sending mail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#sending-mail)

Comment: Address in mailbox given [["rodrigo@area3.cl","rodrigo@l4d.cl"]] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: how can i pass multiple emails ?